# Split URL on final forward slash

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a way to split a Twitter permalink string on its final forward slash, so I can store the tweet_id. Two examples:

```
http://twitter.com/bloombergnews/status/55231572781170688
http://twitter.com/cnn/status/55231572781170688
```

Each URL has a similar format:

```
http://twitter.com/<screen_name>/status/<id_str>
```

With what regular expression would I easily capture  every time?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is not a job for regular expressions, IMHO.

I would do this:

```
$parts = explode('/', rtrim($url, '/'));
$id_str = array_pop($parts);
```

Answer (score 2):

REGX ? yes; *simple one liner*.

$url = 'http://twitter.com/bloombergnews/status/55231572781170688';

---

**Perl**

**($f1 = $url) =~ s/^.*\///;**

print $f1;

---

**PHP**

**$f1 = preg_replace("/^.*\//","",$url);**

echo $f1;

EDIT: backslashes didn't show; fixed in edit box by double \\ (wierd!)